# unable to get full working code for android notification

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-notifications

> I want to show and android notification after some time interval automatically

I have used following `all suggested code snippets` but i'm `failed to get automatic notification` after time 5 minutes for example

```
 public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          String message = "Hellooo, alrm worked ----";
          Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, TripNotification.class); 
          intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
          context.startActivity(intent2);
    }

    public void setAlarm(Context context){
        Log.d("Carbon","Alrm SET !!");

        // get a Calendar object with current time
         Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
         // add 30 seconds to the calendar object
         cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 30);
         Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
         PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 192837, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

         // Get the AlarmManager service
         AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
    }
}


 <receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name="AlarmReceiver"></receiver>
```

Comment: You should use a `BroadcastReceiver` and a broadcast `Intent` rather than an `Activity`.

Comment: Thanks a lot but how? i'm new to android. could you please give me any working code snippet

Comment: Just check the `PendingIntent` and `AlarmManager` documentation.  You just need to create a broadcast pending intent and create a `BroadcastReceiver` in your code and declare in your manifest.  Your receiver can then update the notification.

Comment: I did I have gone through documentation but did not understand where to call the code snipet :(

Comment: Pull down the API samples from your SDK Manager and look at the `AlarmController` and `RepeatingAlarm` classes.  It's a simple test case with a button in the controller UI to set an alarm which is received and posts a `Toast` message.

Comment: code updated in question please check

Comment: What is the intent-filter for which your receiver is registered?

Comment: @Aashish I really do not have any idea i'm new this code snippet I got it from google and it is not working do not know what to do please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to write an `Activity`. Set Alarm for every 5 minutes in the onCreate() method as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ServiceForAlarm.class);
intent.setAction(""+System.currentTimeMillis());

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(m_Context, 0, intent, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 300000L, pendingIntent);
```

In the `ServiceForAlarm`, write code to push notifications.

```
public class ServiceForAlarm extends Service {
        private Context mContext;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
            mContext = getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        SetNotification();
        stopSelf();
    }

private void SetNotification() {
    m_NotificationManager = (NotificationManager)m_Context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    m_Notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon_app, "Your message", System.currentTimeMillis());
    m_Intent = new Intent() ;
    m_PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(m_context, 0, m_Intent, 0);
    m_Notification.contentIntent = m_PendingIntent;
    m_Notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    m_Notification.setLatestEventInfo(m_context, "Title", "Click me", m_PendingIntent);
    m_NotificationManager.notify(1010, m_Notification);
}
```

}

Comment: Is there full code snippet for this? Where is code of `ServiceForAlarm`